# Why is cacerts ignored in Spring Saml?

Tags: spring-saml, opensaml

I've made an implementation based on this with a FilesystemMetadataProvider: https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample

To make the SSL handshake work for the artifact binding I had to put/trust the CA certificate for the IDP in the java keystore used by the keyManager.

I would rather have used the cacerts on the jre in case the IDP changed CA, but I haven't been able to find any property to set so that Spring SAML looks inside that instead.

Also this answer suggest that the cacert is ignored altogheter:
[Spring Security SAML - HTTPS connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435629/spring-security-saml-https-connections/29437890#29437890)

Why is the cacert ignored in Spring SAML? This seems like a deficiency for me.

I have checked that the CA for the IDP is in the cacert file for my jre. If i remove the beans related to TLS/socket factory from the config it still fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, cacerts is ignored. Spring SAML uses custom implementations for handling of trust, with an intention of providing more control over the system's security. You can always quite easily copy over all certificates from cacerts to samlKeystore.

Comment: Oh, Vladimir Schäfer answered my question! Yes I did that, it was good to get an confirmation that it was the "correct" way. Although I would have prefered to have set a property for using the cacerts in the jre instead

Answer (score 0):

Your custom certificate/JDK default certificate must have IDPs certicate imported as trust .
    Your custom certificate used in JKS manager must have at-least one private key.
    Please import your trust in JDK_PATH/jre/lib/securitycacerts  and try the command  *`wget <your_idp_descriptor_url>`*

Comment: I'm not able to understand what you are saying. To make the SSL handshake for the artifact binding to work I had to put the IDP's CA's public SSL certificate in the jks. I want spring saml to look in the cacert instead. The CA certificate is already in the cacert file in the jre