# SAML SP implementation with Jre default key store (cacerts)

Tags: java, spring-security, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have a web application deployed on tomcat. Now I have integrated SAML auth using spring security with it. I am using SP initiated SAML auth.

For this, I have created one key store (JSK) which holds my private key and imported certificate of IDP into it. Followed [this](https://datameer.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205525884-How-to-Setup-a-Java-KeyStore-for-a-SAML-Configuration) steps for generating key store.

Authentication is working fine. Before these I had some certificates in default JRE keystore (lib/security/cacerts) for systems to which my application is interacting. Now as I have used different keystore of SAML, my application is not able to get the certificate imported to default JRE key store. It looks new keystore is overriding the existing default certificates.

So, now I tried to use the same default JRE certificate for SAML as well. Generated private key to same key store and imported IDP certificates to it. But it's not working with that. Giving error like - 
java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big

Searching around I found some thread which talks about ignorance of default JRE keystore like  - [Why is cacerts ignored in Spring Saml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884997/why-is-cacerts-ignored-in-spring-saml) but I could not reach to conclusion.

Is there any way my SALM authentication can work with default JRE keystore so that my existing certificate can be still used ?

Is is possible to have effect of my both the key stores in my application? 1) new key store (created for SALM) 2) existing default JRE key store

Mine is enterprise application and deployed on many customers. So, I can not ask them to re-import all certificates they have in the new key store.

Comment: Using the 'system wide key/trusstore' is actually a bad idea as it's overwritten when you deploy a new JDK , e.g. because the operating guys deploy a security patch.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr, Yah. True. But actually my product is having own JRE bundled with it. so, it's not using system's any existing JRE, instead it's using product's own JRE.

Comment: Even then ... what if you get patch for your app that updates the JRE. Unfortunately I've seen this quite often in productive environments.